# Filter out items in pandas dataframe by index number (in one column)

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a column in my dataframe that goes indexwise from 900 to 1200.
Now I want to extract that index values automatically. Does anyone know how I could do that? I either would like to have the difference (1200-900) or the range [900,1200].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
out = (df.index.min(), df.index.max())

dif = df.index.max() - df.index.min()

#1200 missing
r = range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())

#include 1200
r1 = range(df.index.min(), df.index.max() + 1)
```